# simple Haskell loop

Tags: loops, haskell, io

I just started learning Haskell, but the absence of loops is infinitely frustrating right now. I figured out how to write loops for functions. My problem, however, is that I want to output some results while iterating the loop. It seems that I have to use debug to perform this simple task.

So right now I would just appreciate an example of how to print out a string 10 times in the main structure.

In other words, I want to do this 10 times:

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "a string"
```

Thanks. I feel this will be very illuminating for my task.

Comment: The real question to be answered here is that when you want to do "loops" in a functional language, you use recursion.  The only pesky thing is that if you look at it: the types don't line up, because of the monad constructor (IO, in this case).  Because of that, you need a recursive structure that "splices in" the monadic bind all the way down.  In other words, this is just recursion, with a slight variation to handle the "special" way Haskell treats IO.

Comment: Even I am a beginner to Haskell but I'd like to share what little insight I've gained. Someone told me that when you want to do loops in Haskell think of either recursion or list comprehensions. Not relevant to your question here, but suppose you want to add all the elements in a list. Of course you need to iterate over all the elements. Recursion will work, and so will using a list comprehension.

Comment: @JohnRed I don't think you can sum a list up with LC. LC is basically just `flatMap`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could define a recursive function that prints "a string" n times (n being the parameter of the function), like this:

```
printStringNTimes 0 = return ()
printStringNTimes n =
 do
  putStrLn "a string"
  printStringNTimes (n-1)

main = printStringNTimes 10
```

A somewhat more general approach would be to define a function that repeats any IO action n times:

```
repeatNTimes 0 _ = return ()
repeatNTimes n action =
 do
  action
  repeatNTimes (n-1) action

main = repeatNTimes 10 (putStrLn "a string")
```

The above function already exists in `Control.Monad` under the name `replicateM_`.

Answer (score 47):

Well Haskell's IO is a bit tricky when you're just starting out since it's based on monads.

Your problem though has a simple solution:

```
main = replicateM_ 10 $ putStrLn "a string"
```

This is using the combinator `replicateM_` from `Control.Monad`

It has lots of useful functions for composing and executing monadic actions.

Comment: To elaborate on your answer for his benefit: Haskell has `for` and `while` loops, but they are library functions rather than language built-ins.  For example, the equivalent of a `for` loop is the `forM_` combinator from `Control.Monad`.  In this case, though, `replicateM_` is more concise.

Answer (score 4):

I am also a beginner of Haskell, and I have a solution that is less elegant and yet is pragmatically useful.

```
main = do 
    putStr result
    where
        string = "a string"
        result = concat [string ++ "\n" | i <- [1,2..10]]
```

So here, we have defined a list, the elements of which are the strings that you want to print out followed by a new line character.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most imperative looking form of doing a for loop is:

```
for list action = mapM_ action list

main :: IO Int
main = do
    for [0..10] (\ i -> do

        print(i^2)
        )
    return 0
```

This actually looks pretty much like C code to me.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like to this allows you to loop a specific function, making it more reusable (instead of writing it out for each new thing you want to loop).

```hs
loop :: Int -> (IO()) -> IO()
loop 0 _ = return ()
loop n f =
 do
  f
  loop (n - 1) f
```

Examples:

```hs
main = do
 loop 5 (do
  putStr "hello "
  putStrLn "there")
```

```
main = do
 loop 3 (do
  loop 4 (putStrLn "Hi")
  putStrLn ""
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

```hs
n = 10
doSomething () = putStrLn "a string"
main = sequence (replicate n (doSomething()))
```

- `sequence`: sequentially solve each `IO a` in a list
- `replicate n ele`: build a list which repeats `ele` for `n` times, like `take n (repeat ele)`