# Creating list comprehension from scratch in haskell using monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension, monads

I am trying to create an interpreter as an exercise that I have come across, and the interpreter should also be able to make a list comprehension that should work similar to the original Haskell-list comprehension. In the version in the exercise however the list comprehension shall be evaluated as part of an `eval`-function with below signature:

`eval :: Expr -> Comp Value`

Where

```
data Expr =
    Const Value
  | Var VName    
  | Call FuncName [Expr]
  | List [Expr]
  | Compr Expr [ExprClause]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data ExprClause =
    ForCl VName Expr
  | IfCl Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

Furthermore where `Comp` refers to a monad with `newtype Comp a = Comp {runComp :: Env -> (Either RunErr a, [String]) }`´as constructor.

And where

```
data Value =     
  | IntVal Int
  | StringVal String
  | ListVal [Value]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data VName = String
```

When the `eval`-function is given `Compr eBody [ForCl VName Expr]`, each occurrance for `ForCl` will correspond to a for-loop for the variable named by `VName`, such that e.g. `eval (Compr (2*x) [ForCl (Var "x") (Call "range" (Const (IntVal 10)))]` will be equivalent to the python list comrpehension `[2*x for x in range 10]`

I am able to create a function that looks like the following:

```
eval (Compr eBody [(ForCl vname e)]) = 
  let body = [(eval eBody) | eBody <- [e]]  
  in 
  do   
  values <- sequence $ body  
  return (ListVal values)
```

While it does compile it doesn't take `vname` into account such that the input given in `VName` points to the same variable as the one (possibly) contained in the `eBody`.
This might require more Monadic computations and involvement than what I imply in my solution. This is however something I am unsure of.

Can you give me some ideas how to make before mentioned 'co-reference', such that that I might also be able to deal with several variables contained in `eBody` and with each their `ForCl`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the section on list comprehensions in the Haskell Report. Monads aren't assumed, only the `concatMap` function. It includes a suggested translation of the list-comprehension syntax to more basic constructs.

Comment: @chepner , Yup, I am already familier with https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension  which I think you might be refering to.

Comment: No, I mean https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11.

Comment: (Granted, your language would need to support `let` expressions to use the translation found in the Report, as well as Boolean values.)

Comment: Doesn't haskell support `let` by default?

Comment: Haskell does, but your expression type doesn't have a `Let` constructor that would let you rewrite *your* `Compr` in the same way.

Comment: But then that would require me to create my own `Let`-constructor as well, for isntance using `data Let = Const Value` !? It would however need to be fitted to the types I already have why I chose `Const Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[(eval e0) | e0 <- [e]]` is equivalent to `[eval e]`, which is not what you intended. You aren’t using the original `e0` at all here, but another local variable with the same name.

Since you haven’t shown the definition of `Env` I’ll assume `type Env = [(VName, Value)]` for now. Where you wrote `data VName = String`, I believe you meant `type VName = String`. And where you wrote `CCFor`, I’ll assume you meant `ForCl`.

If you haven’t done so already, to implement local variable binding, you can include a case for `eval (Var vname)` (using e.g. `lookup`), and add a way to update the local environment, such as this:

```
withVar :: VName -> Value -> Comp a -> Comp a
withVar name value comp =
  Comp $ \ env -> runComp ((name, value) : env) comp
```

Now, your goal is to implement a transformation that simplifies the list comprehension one clause at a time. For example, `[e | x <- xs, y <- ys]` is equivalent to the concatenation of `[e | y <- ys]` evaluated for each value `x` from in `xs`. And a comprehension with no clauses remaining is simply a list.

Since `eval` produces a `Value`, but here we are always working with lists, I will introduce two helper functions. The first will just check for a list value.

```
needList :: Value -> Comp [Value]
needList (ListVal xs) = pure xs
needList _ = {- Raise an error. -}
```

The other, local to `eval`, will evaluate a list comprehension. It can iterate over the clauses recursively, using `withVar` to bind each variable.

When reaching the end, it should evaluate the comprehension’s main expression.

```
eval (Compr e0 clauses0) = ListVal <$> evalCompr clauses0
  where

    evalCompr :: [ExprClause] -> Comp [Value]

    evalCompr (ForCl vname e : clauses) = do

      list <- needList =<< eval e

      results <- for list $ \value -> do
        withVar vname value (evalCompr clauses)

      {- Collect results. (Hint: ‘>>=’.) -}

    evalCompr (IfCl e : clauses) =
      {- Filter results. (Hint: ‘guard’.) -}

    evalCompr [] = do
      value <- eval e0
      {- Produce one result. (Hint: ‘pure’.) -}
```

I’ll leave the rest for you to fill in on your own.

Comment: it is correct with my mistakes in the inconsistent variable names. And also correct with how you defined `Env`. Likewise I have a similar function to `withvar`. I think I understand the gist of your approach and I find it a fascinating way to go about it.

Comment: I also suspect that the `for` you use is problematic and will at the very least need to be declared as a function like they do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004365/simple-haskell-loop , where they use `mapM_` for that, since `for`-loops arent a native part of haskell.

Comment: Another question, Isn't  `pure` something that is used for `Applicative (functors)` and can't one use `return xs` instead of `pure xs` in the helper function you have created?

Comment: I have now attempted to fill out the blanks as you suggested. I still have a few things that doesn't entirely work. especially in the `ForCl` where i have used `forM`. I still however get some errors when trying to use a `look` function I have created.

Comment: @Piskator: [`pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure) is equivalent to `return`, so you could use `return` here. The only difference is that `pure` works for more types, so I use it out of habit. Same with [`for`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:for) vs. `forM`. I think the guidelines on Stack Overflow say that, because your code has substantially changed, you should make a new post about it and include a link to this answer for context.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon. I shall make a new post then.