# How to create a For and if clause when designing list comprehension for an interpreter in Haskell using Monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension, monads

I am trying to create a list comprehension from scratch in Haskell as part of some exercises I have come across in which you have to build an interpreter. I am part of the way in implementing it based on suggestions in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632149/creating-list-comprehension-from-scratch-in-haskell-using-monads)
As a follow up I have created the below code so far which follows the above suggestions and the functions defined in there.

I have tried to to do a number of things to solve the problem.

Firstly I have tried using a function `look` to 'collect' the values of variables that are bound to the Monad (see above link for details). `look` doesn't take a monad as an argument However and since it uses the Haskell lookup function besides, it will be hard to make any elegant code with it that wouldn't require some extensive coding with another `forM` as I have used below if a `Comp [Value]` rather than `Comp Value` were to be returned.

Secondly, I have tried to use `return concat results` in order to flatten `results`, I suspect however that this will not return the values for only the variable `vname` but will return all values of all variables in the Comp Monad at hand.

How can I define my function such that the `ForCl`-branch will work as intended?

**EDIT**

Below is what I believe to be a MRE as I understood it from what was referenced in the comments. Hopefully this help. As can be seen I have commented out the `IfCl` since this will be the next step in what I try to understand and implement.

```
import Control.Monad

type Env = [(VName, Value)]

data RErr = EBadArg String | EBadVar String
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Expr =
    Const Value
  | Var VName    
  | Call FuncName [Expr]
  | List [Expr]
  | Compr Expr [ExprClause]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Value =     
    IntV Int
  | FalseV | TrueV
  | StringV String
  | ListV [Value]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data ExprClause =
    ForCl VName Expr
  | IfCl Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

type VName = String
type FuncName = String

newtype Comp a = Comp {runComp :: Env -> (Either RErr a, [String]) }

instance Monad Comp where
  return a = Comp (\_ -> (Right a, []))
  m >>= f = Comp (\env ->                        
        case runComp m env of 
          (Left a, strLst) -> (Left a, strLst)
          (Right a, strLst) -> let (a', strLst') = runComp (f a) env in (a', strLst ++ strLst'))

instance Functor Comp where
  fmap = liftM
instance Applicative Comp where
  pure = return; (<*>) = ap

abandon :: RErr -> Comp a
abandon re = Comp(\env -> (Left re, []))

needList :: Value -> Comp [Value]
needList (ListV xs) = return xs -- pure xs 
needList _ = abandon (EBadArg "Error due to Bad Arg")

truthmaker :: Value -> Bool
truthmaker FalseV = False
truthmaker (IntV 0) = False --True
truthmaker (StringV "") = False 
truthmaker (ListV []) = False 
truthmaker _ = True

look :: VName -> Comp Value
look x = Comp(\env ->    
  case lookup x env of  
    Nothing -> (Left (EBadVar x), [])    
    Just y -> (Right y, []))

withVar :: VName -> Value -> Comp a -> Comp a
withVar x v m = Comp(\env -> runComp m ((x,v):env))

eval (Compr eBody clauses0) = ListV <$> evalComprHelp clauses0
  where 
    evalComprHelp :: [ExprClause] -> Comp [Value]
  
    evalComprHelp (ForCl vname e : clauses) = do
        listOfValues <- needList =<< eval e    
  
        results <- forM listOfValues $ \value -> do 
            withVar vname value (evalComprHelp clauses) -- >>= (look vname)
        return (concat results)
        --return results
{-
    evalComprHelp (IfCl e : clauses) = do
      listOfValues <- compValList =<< eval e
      results <- forM listOfValues $ \value -> do
        guard (truthmaker (value))
      results
  -}  
    evalComprHelp [] = do    
      value <- eval eBody
      return [value]
```

The `IfCl` still confuses me abit but I might leave that for now, although I would be nice if someone could give some hints about the relationship between that and the `ForCl` and if it in some cases will traverse over the tail of the list givin to the former the `clauses`.

Comment: Your wording is very confusing. Are you trying to write an interpreter for a  language that includes list comprehensions?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I am trying to do. I can perhaps change the title a bit.

Comment: A [mcve] would be really helpful.

Comment: I tried to include a MRE in my edit above. Hopefully it is helpful.